# Почему не видит файл?

Tags: java, аудио

```
public class TestRAF {

public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {

    try {
        File soundFile = new File("SoundAlert.wav"); //Звуковой файл
        System.out.println(soundFile.getAbsoluteFile());

        //Получаем AudioInputStream
        //Вот тут могут полететь IOException и UnsupportedAudioFileException
        AudioInputStream ais = AudioSystem.getAudioInputStream(soundFile);

        //Загружаем наш звуковой поток в Clip
        //Может выкинуть IOException и LineUnavailableException
        try (
            //Получаем реализацию интерфейса Clip
            //Может выкинуть LineUnavailableException
            Clip clip = AudioSystem.getClip()) {
            //Загружаем наш звуковой поток в Clip
            //Может выкинуть IOException и LineUnavailableException
            clip.open(ais);

            clip.setFramePosition(0); //устанавливаем указатель на старт
            clip.start(); //Поехали!!!

            //Если не запущено других потоков, то стоит подождать, пока клип не закончится
            //В GUI-приложениях следующие 3 строчки не понадобятся
            Thread.sleep(clip.getMicrosecondLength() / 1000);
            clip.stop(); //Останавливаем
            clip.close(); //Закрываем
        }
    } catch (IOException | UnsupportedAudioFileException | LineUnavailableException | InterruptedException exc) {
        System.out.println(exc);
    }

}
```

}

Собственно говоря, вот так `File soundFile = new File("SoundAlert.wav");` - файл не виден, но когда вставляю полный путь, то файл виден.
*C:\Users\Пользователь\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testRAF\src\testraf\SoundAlert.wav*

`System.out.println(soundFile.getAbsoluteFile());` - вывод:
*C:\Users\Пользователь\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testRAF\SoundAlert.wav*
Вот скриншот директории проекта: http://joxi.ru/Dr8EBbYike8Gem
В чём причина?

Comment: относительный путь считается от рабочего каталога программы (папки проекта в вашем случае), а у вас файл лежит в пакете.

Comment: Ага, а как сделать тогда правильно?

Comment: Как же тогда здесь работает? https://habrahabr.ru/post/191422/

Answer (score 1):

Например, можно поместить файл в нужный каталог `C:\Users\Пользователь\Documents\NetBeansProjects\testRAF\src\testraf\dist\SoundAlert.wav` т.е. где находится исполняемый java файл

Comment: А как же он будет запускаться потом, когда будет собран jar файл ?

Comment: @Prototype, так он и не будет собираться в jar файле. Его отдельно нужно будете таскать. Вот если бы вы его в проект как ресурс подцепили, тогда совсем другое дело.

Comment: Мне именно это и надо. Как сделать так, что бы он в проекте находился постоянно и корректно читался?

Comment: @Prototype, но ваш вопрос совсем о другом спрашивает. Тут правило: один вопрос для одной темы